# Sybase Bulk Copy

Tags: c#, ado.net, copy, bulk

We can add one more column in the iC_ProductImageAssociation  table  called 'ProductFeatureApplicabilityId'

this column will refer to the iC_ProductFeatureApplicability. So when a product suppose ABC with ProductFeature of Color 'RED' is  inserted in the iC_ProductFeatureApplicability we can take this ProductFeatureApplicabilityId and store in the iC_ProductImageAssociation table.

so now Image can be applied to a product or to a ProductFeature or Both. Also i am planning to produce a alternate ProductFeature Data Model.

in which rather than storing individual columns as a feature (like currently in iC_ProductFeature table, we are storing Color, Size , Brand ect as a separate columns ), we can create a master table of the Product Features (iC_ProductFeatureMasters) that will store all these columns  as rows and **at runtime administor can define more features**

so iC_ProductFeatureMasters will store the data as

```
ProductFeatureMasterId                        FeatureName 

 1                                            Color

 2                                            Size

 3                                            Brand 

 4                                            Dimensions
```

and iC_ProductFeature Table will store the ProductFeatureMasterId  and its value.

so now iC_ProductFeature will look like below

```
ProductFeatureId               ProductFeatureMasterId     Description         UOM ID  

 1                                    1                       RED
 2                                    4                       10                     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example from my code:

```
var table = new DataTable();
var sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dataBaseConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTransaction) { DestinationTableName = destinationTableName};
sqlCopy.WriteToServer(table);
```

You can find more information by following the links below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server

You cannot do BulkCopy for several tables so you need to BulkCopy for each of your tables.
For transactional behavior you should create Transaction object and pass in the constructors of BulkCopy objects.

Comment: Sql Server bulk copy won't work on Sybase.  But there are bulk copy methods in the Sybase ASE drivers for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, the triggers and other logic that needs to be executed with each row insert is what is keeping things slow, not the insert method.  Even bulk copy will not be fast if it needs to execute triggers.

I'd recommend refactoring the logic to run on all of the rows after they have been inserted, rather than one at a time.  Normally you'd create staging tables for the new data, where it would be stored while being processed and before being merged with the regular data tables.